# Oracle ordering of results using a mixed varchar column but numeric where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a table with a `VARCHAR2` column which contains values that are a mixture of pure-numbers and alpha-numerics. I have a `CODE` column that contains:

```
200
215
220
A553
D545
etc.
```

The following query works:

```
select *
from   TABLE
where  CLASS = 3
AND    (CODE >= 210 and CODE < 220) or CODE = 291)
```

Values that are CLASS 3 are always numeric.

But when I add a `ORDER BY`, it doesn't work:

```
select *
from   TABLE
where  CLASS = 3
and    (CODE >= 210 and CODE < 220) or CODE = 291)
ORDER BY CODE
```

instead I get `ORA-01722: invalid number`. This [seems to be](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01722_invalid_number.htm) because the Oracle Optimiser is assessing the "order by" before the where clause, and thus non-numeric values get assessed.

I have tried changing it to `ORDER BY TO_CHAR(CODE)` but to no affect. Similar negative result with trying to place it all into a sub-query.

So, how do I order the results of this query by `CODE` (`ASC`ending)? I guess I can specify all possible `CODE` values manually in the where clause as strings (i.e. `code = '210' or code = '211' or...`), but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: It is not clear that the data you posted is for which column? Please post a working test case, i.e. **create and insert statements** and show your desired output.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I've clarified the quest a little; the list of examples are the "CODE" column which is the problem column.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table and what version Oracle? I can't replicate the issue on your simple dataset with no indexes on Oracle 11g (it executes without exceptions).

Comment: @MT0 - It seems there is a UNIQUE index on the CODE column; Oracle 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be in your `WHERE` condition, given that it forces Oracle to cast your code to number;

Try keeping the `WHERE` condition in `varchar2` format:

```
with TABLE_(code, class_) as
(
select '200',3 from dual union all
select '215',3 from dual union all
select '220',3 from dual union all
select 'A553',3 from dual union all
select 'D545',3 from dual
)
select *
from   TABLE_
where  CLASS_ = 3
and   ( (CODE >= '210' and CODE < '220') or CODE = '291')
ORDER BY CODE
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE '2101' >= '210' AND '2101' < '220'`

Comment: Yep, it's as simple as putting quotes around the items in the WHERE clause. Never thought to try that. Thanks.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan No, it is not that simple. Try what MTO said, `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE '2101' >= '210' AND '2101' < '220'`

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan This will not work if you have a code such as `2101` as this is between `210` and `220` when you are doing string comparisons.

Comment: @MT0 - thanks for the warning. Fortunately all my codes are only 3 digits in the db.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan Can you guarantee that for 1, 5 or 10 years into the future and will you need to debug this query to find the error if you do start having 4-or-more digit codes that start appearing erroneously?

Comment: @MT0 - No, which is why I included the `Length(code) = 3` from the other answers. I agree that future-proofing is important!

Answer (score 2):

The `ORDER BY` has nothing to do with the problem -- at least not directly.

SQL in general, and Oracle in particular, make no promises about the order of evaluation of conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  Hence, the `WHERE` clause is not (necessarily) evaluated in the order written.  The presence of the `ORDER BY` might affect the order of evaluation of the conditions in this particular case.

In general, it is really bad practice to mix data types, the way that you are doing it.  But, you can guarantee the order of evaluation by using `case`:

```
select *
from   TABLE
where  CLASS = 3 
       'true' = (case when class <> 3 then 'false'
                      when (CODE >= 210 and CODE < 220) or CODE = 291) then 'true'
                 end);
```

*I do not recommend doing this.*  I only want to point out that `case` does force the order of evaluation of the conditions.

The correct solution is to use string comparisons.  In this case, I would go with:

```
select *
from   TABLE
where  CLASS = 3 AND
       CODE in ('210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '291')
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
where  CLASS = 3 and length(CODE) = 3 and
       ((CODE >= '210' and CODE < '220') or CODE = '291')
```

Note that for accuracy you do need to take the length into account.

Answer (score 1):

Since the **data type** of code column is **VARCHAR2**, you must compare it as a string in the `where` clause not as a number.

Simple **error reproduction**:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY = 10;
SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY = 10
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL>
```

You need to use **single-quotation marks** to make it a string and pass the values as **IN-list** rather than a **range**. Numeric operations on characters will use **ASCII** value for arithmetic.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT '210' code FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '2101' code FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '220' code FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'A123' code FROM dual
  6  )
  7  --end of sample_data mimicking real table
  8  SELECT code
  9  FROM sample_data
 10  WHERE code IN ('210', '220')
 11  ORDER BY code;

CODE
----
210
220

SQL>
```

Now coming to the **ORDERING** of rows as **number** and not **string**, you must use **TO_NUMBER** in the `SELECT` and use the same alias in the `ORDER BY` clause.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT '210' code FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '2101' code FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '220' code FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'A123' code FROM dual
  6  )
  7  --end of sample_data mimicking real table
  8  SELECT to_number(code) code_num
  9  FROM sample_data
 10  WHERE code IN ('210', '220')
 11  ORDER BY code_num;

  CODE_NUM
----------
       210
       220
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  class = 3
AND    (  ( code >= '210' AND code < '220' AND LENGTH( code ) = 3 )
       OR code = '291' )
ORDER BY CODE;
```