# ORA-01722 when trying to use ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've got the following simple SQL query which returns data fine:

```
select ticket_id,executor_id
from e2efr
where executor_id in (60882,91279)
```

When I want to sort it with:

```
select ticket_id,executor_id
from e2efr
where executor_id in (60882,91279)
order by ticket_id
```

I get the error message:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

How that can be!?

Comment: What column types are ticket_id and executor_id? varchar2 or number?

Comment: Please post your table definition, I guess that ticket_id/**executor_id** is VARCHAR/CHAR/CLOB. Oracle knows how to sort.

Comment: My guess: The column `executor_id` is not numeric and some rows contain non-numeric data. So it must be converted to a number in order to get compared with 60882 and 91279. Oracle fails on the second query, as could be expected. Somehow, however the execution plan for the first query allows Oracle to circumvent this issue.

Comment: To solve the issue if it's as @ThorstenKettner described, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938768/oracle-ordering-of-results-using-a-mixed-varchar-column-but-numeric-where-clause)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: if there was a problem converting `executor_id` shouldn't that also appear without using `order by`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oracle sql developer only fetches the first 50 rows by default. Therefore it may be that the malicious data is not being selected and the error doesnt occour. see `with testtab as ( select '1' as "COL1", '3' as "COL2" from dual union all select '4', '4' from dual union all select '4', '5' from dual union all select '4', null from dual union all select 'jop', '7' from dual ) select * from testtab where col1 < 5 /*order by col2 desc*/ fetch first 1 rows only;`

Comment: @Chrᴉz: but the `order by` is evaluated on the server before SQL Developer even sees the data

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, but the error doesnt occour in the order by but in the where condition. if the first 50 results that match dont cause a error, why sould oracle check all others as well? As you can see in the execution plan the data is fetched ordered before the condition is being applied(in my example `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NLSSORT("TESTTAB"."COL2",'nls_sort=''GERMAN''') DESC )<=1`)

Comment: But I'm sure this may change depending on the table size, indices etc as well. In other circumstances oracle perhaps first filters and then orders.

Comment: A test case with sample data would help here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Many times in tables with larger amount of records, when we scroll down, sometimes the query does fail with this error message. so I would side with Chriz :) By scroll down I mean, keep on fetching 50 records one by one using sql developer

Comment: Problem is with EXECUTOR_ID which is VARCHAR2(100) while TICKET_ID is NUMBER. Problem did not occured without ORDER BY because as somebody prevously said SQL Developer fetches only limited number of records. When I tried to export or list all records I encountered the ORA-01722 problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the numbers as strings. Some of the values in executor_id cannot be converted to number and hence you are getting the error.

```
select ticket_id,executor_id
from e2efr
where executor_id in ('60882','91279')
order by ticket_id
```

Comment: If that was the case, then wouldn't the first query in the question also result in that error? But sbrbot claims without the order by the query works

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not sure, but maybe this is something to do with the way optimizer works. no optimization/different optimization for the query without the `order by` clause. I am not sure, but maybe that is possible

Comment: Problem is with EXECUTOR_ID which is VARCHAR2 while TICKET_ID is NUMBER. (Who coud think at first that column with numbers is VARCHAR type!) This mislead me too, but problem did not occur without ORDER BY because, as somebody prevously said, SQL Developer (and other tools) fetches only limited number of records. When I tried to export or list all records I encountered the ORA-01722 problem as well.